# Cannot access org.apache.lucene.search.TotalHits

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I'm using the following dependency:

```maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

All of version 7.10.1 with Lucene dependency:

```maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>8.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>8.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get the following error:

```
java: cannot access org.apache.lucene.search.TotalHits
  class file for org.apache.lucene.search.TotalHits not found.
```

when I run

```java
searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits().value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

These 3 dependencies are enough and while importing SearchResponse Do it from elasticsearch

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
```